# When generating XSDs using Eclipse it nevers finishes

Tags: eclipse, xsd, jaxb

I extract the data tables into JPA annotated java files, updated and change to xml annotation.  Using Eclipse -

1. file new
2. other
3. JAXB Schema from JAXB classes.

Eclipse generates the XSD, but is then "locked" in a 100% creating XSD, requiring kill -9 and a restart

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you please edit your question to include your problem and question in the body of question (rather than only the title).

Comment: That's an improvement but you really need also to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks.